# HTML color input does not change the selected value in FireFox

Tags: html

I am trying to use the HTML5 `color` selector. When a user change their selection, the select color does not always show up. Note the same works with Google Chrome but not FireFox.

How can I show the selected color when the user change their selection using FireFox?

Here is an example where the first 3 inputs, the selected color does not change.

```html
<form>

<h3>Does not work with default #0000000</h3>
<input type="color" value="#000000" name="bgColor" />


<h3>Does not work with default #ffffff</h3>
<input type="color" value="#ffffff" name="fColor" />


<h3>Does not work with NO default</h3>
<input type="color" value="" name="oColor" />

<h3>Works with other default value</h3>
<input type="color" value="#4287f5" name="o2Color" />

</form>
```

Comment: Not sure what's the problem. I have tested the code snippet and it does work. Might be your browser/versions?

Comment: @JoshuaOoi it works in Google Chrome but not FireFox. I updated the question

Comment: It does work in firefox too. You need to make sure that you did adjust the most right color bar.